# how can I write rest api for different category in one time

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have different different category like man women kids and I want to see more then one category related data in one time to using req.query in react then how I have to write rest api  in mongodb for this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write REST API in MongoDB? MongoDB is a database. You can write REST API in NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

you need first to make the backend , one solution is to use the aggregation framework in mongo or to make nested query or use graphQl so the goal is get the data,
then use react-query lib to parse the query to specify what category to show , then you can send it to backend .

for easier but not effective in much scenarios is to make different request for each category and aggregate the data at the front side , it is expensive solution but easier and if the data not fetched to much it will be good.